# Flutter: App is crashing after using multiple image assets

Tags: flutter

I am using bottom navigation bar in my application and created 4 class to navigate to different screen. I have some png images to show on my every navigation screen and used following code for it:

```
Image.asset(
            image,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
          )
```

but when I run my application it's load first three images but when I open 4th navigation screen app is crashing. How to fix this issue?

[edit]: In some devices image loading after some delay and in some devices app is crashing.

[image]

Comment: Have you received any error? Could you update here..

Comment: @MTM not getting any error in log! I think there is low memory issue. When i add a high resolution image app crash but when i add low resolution image it works properly but in my case when i load 3 image it work properly but before loading 4th image app is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Please use width and height according your need
Container(
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
image: new DecorationImage(
image: new AssetImage("assets/Background_rv.jpg"),
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a low memory problem. You just need to set `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight` in `Image.asset` If you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the image as is set one of the values, and the ratio will remain true. You should also choose smaller size images as you don't need your images to be needlessly large. For example if you want your image to display in 200x200 box then set `cacheWidth` to `200 * window.devicePixelRatio.ceil()` you will find `window` in `dart:ui`

Also keep an eye on your debug tools. Many people face this problem, but never know about it because their apps don't crash. Check your memory consumption in the debug tools

Cheers

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer and it'll solve my problem 90%, issue is by adding cacheHeight and cacheWidth, when app open first time image takes some times to load but after that it loading without any delay, so how to fix delay loading at first time?

Comment: You probably need to load different resolutions of your  images depending on the device's pixel ratio check out this part of the docs on how to do that https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-images. My guess is that this will speed things up. Generally if you can control the image resolution before it's even loaded you should prefer that over using `cacheWidth` or `cacheHeight` and have the app do the work.

Answer (score -1):

BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: ImageIcon(
AssetImage("images/bottomnavICoN.png"),
color: Color(0xFF3A5A98),
),
title: Text('Home'),
),

Comment: Not getting my actual problem, see my edited question.